# binding inside html helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want to bind to the display style property of my Html.TextBox

```
<%= Html.TextBox("RunDates", Model.RunDates, new { style = "display: none" })%>
```

is this possible? i want to do something like the following that i know works for me:

```
<input id="btnBack" class="btnAction" type="button" value="Back" style="display: <%= Model.IsEnabledProductSetupBack?"inline":"none" %>;" />
```

or is there a way to post `<input type="text"` ... in mvc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom Html helper for this. There are 2 possibilities:

1. You replace this weakly typed TextBox helper with strongly typed TextBoxFor by taking advantage of a view model (which is what I would recommend) in which case you will be able to write your textbox like this:

   ```
   <%= Html.MyTextBoxFor(x => x.RunDates) %>
   ```
2. You stick with weak typing in which case the best you could get is this:

   ```
   <%= Html.TextBox("RunDates", Model.RunDates, Html.SelectStyle(Model.IsEnabledProductSetupBack)) %>
   ```

Now since I recommend the first solution, it is the one I would provide same code for:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString MyTextBoxFor<TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<MyViewModel> helper, 
        Expression<Func<MyViewModel, TProperty>> ex
    )
    {
        var model = helper.ViewData.Model;
        var htmlAttributes = new RouteValueDictionary();
        htmlAttributes["style"] = "display: none;";
        if (model.IsEnabledProductSetupBack)
        {
            htmlAttributes["style"] = "display: inline;";
        }
        return helper.TextBoxFor(ex, htmlAttributes);
    }
}
```